# Is there some way to run solace queue locally like with ActiveMQ?

Tags: solace-mq

Is there some way to run Solace queue locally like with ActiveMQ?

Below is the explanation of what I mean:

I've a microservice on Spring integretion that is consuming MQ messages, so for testing it locally I run activemq-all.jar, start my microservice and push messages into localhost queue with Hermes JMS.

So the question: is there some way I can do same thing with Solace queues and topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a Solace broker in Docker locally on your machine to run your tests against.
Have a look at the docs here to help you get started: 
https://docs.solace.com/Solace-SW-Broker-Set-Up/Docker-Containers/Set-Up-Docker-Container-Image.htm